# setPersistence on Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have tried t implement a method of persisted authentication following firebase online tutorial.
I wrote the following code:

```
const signIn = async () => {
  await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
  await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  navigate("/Account")
}
```

where the imports are:

```
import { browserLocalPersistence, getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider , setPersistence, signInWithPopup} from "firebase/auth"
```

However everytime I refresh the application the it logs me out of the website. Does anybody know what the problem is

I tried following the tutorial attentively and I have made sure that setPersistence runs before signInWithPopup but it is just not working

Comment: You're supposed to use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to know when the user is definitely signed in or not.  If you're using currentUser, you should know that doesn't get updated immediately on page load.  You have to wait for the first observer callback.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a desktop browser-based app, then persistence is enabled automatically.

However, login persistence isn't detected with the code you provided above.  It is handled by your code running `onAuthStateChanged()` , the "listener" in your browser that gets notified when login has completed successfully.  Login is an *asynchronous process*, so you want to have that listener running to let your app know when login is complete.

[Here's a simple "starter app"](https://github.com/gregfenton/react-and-user-profiles-with-firebase-auth-and-firestore) you can experiment with that showcases React + Firebase Authentication, including automatically logging a user in if they didn't log out previously.  See the information in the project's README.

Comment: So would I have to set the persistence inside the function of the listener onAuthStateChanged() ?

Comment: You don't need to set persistence if this is a browser app. It is on by default.